I need redirect /item/x to /item/y in .htaccess
I have rules in .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)/?$ item.php/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,NC]

Which redirects to /item/page
I removed one item from the store and now I need redirect /item/x to /item/y
Tried to redirect this way but it doesn't work
Redirect ^/item/x$ /item/y
Redirect https://testsite.org/item/x https://testsite.org/item/y
Redirect /item/x https://testsite.org/item/y


Why would you suddenly want to use a different module than the one you implemented your previous rules in? Why not stick with the rule you already know and implement another rule based on the rewriting module? So as a RewriteRule?
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^item/x$ item/y [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)/?$ item.php/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,NC]


Well it doesn't have to be, I've just always used a redirect

@AC1D The issue is that you were trying to use a regular expression with the Redirect directive. Which does not support regular expressions, but only literal subjects. That is clearly documented. So I wonder: did you ever bother to check the documentation? Why not? ;-)

Glad I could be of help, though.
